# How to calculate the heat energy lost to two steel electrodes in contact with a piece of heated Titanium in a Vacuum

Tags: thermodynamics, vacuum, heat-conduction

Say within a vacuum chamber I have two steel electrodes in contact with 0.0006 m^2 of Titanium heated to a temperature of 1,800 degrees Kelvin.  How would I calculate the heat energy lost via contact with with those two pieces of steel?

I am attempting to calculate the power necessary to sustain the Titanium at a specific temperature, 1,800 degrees kelvin. Therefore I assume I need to calculate the heat lost to the environment and then power required to combat that loss. Since this is being done in a vacuum the only conductive heat transfer is via the two steel pieces that clamp down on an area of approximately 0.0006 m^2 of Titanium.  I am ignoring heat lost via radiation.

I used Q = hA(T2 - T1) and calculated 11.232 Watts,  which does not seem to correct as the power necessary to heat the titanium to 1,800 degrees kelvin is 16.8434 watts. Perhaps I am wrong.

Q = 14.4 W/(mk) x 0.0006 m^2 x 1,300 K
(I found that the pieces were +/- 500 degrees kelvin immediately after the initial heating process 1,300 = 1,800-500)
Q = 11.232 Watts

Comment: What does the convective heat transfer equation you used have to do with conduction along the wires?  You should be looking at a combination of actual conduction along the wires and radiation, and treating the wires like cooling fins.

Comment: The reason I am ignoring radiation is that I have already taken that into consideration,  specifically I am trying to find the heat lost to the two steel clamps that make contact with 0.0006 m^2 of a piece of the Titanium foil.  I don't necessarily need to find an answer so precise as to warrant the calculation of heat lost to the wiring system.  Just to those clamps.  Is there a different equation that I should be using to calculate this rather than the derivation of Fourier's Law as I used above?